# Can I use a return ticket to leave from Birmingham International and return to New Street?

Tags: england, train-stations, national-rail

I will be flying to Birmingham in a few days. I will go somewhere else near Banbury for a few days and then return to the city.

If I buy an off-peak return ticket BHI-BAN-BHI or BHM-BAN-BHM for that journey will I be able to leave in BHM resp. get onto the platform in BHI? And wil that be a legitimate way of travelling? Or do I need to buy two separate tickets for BHI-BAN and BAN-BHM?

Comment: I'd suggest [asking in the Rail UK Forums - Fares Advice & Policy section](http://www.railforums.co.uk/forumdisplay.php?f=105) - those folks seem to know the rules many orders of magnitude better than most!

Answer (score 2):

It depends on which train ticket you buy.

[The Off-Peak Saver Return on Birmingham Stations to Banbury](http://www.brfares.com/#faredetail?orig=0418&dest=BAN&tkt=SVR) permits a break-of-journey on the outbound portion, so you could join the train at Birmingham Airport.

I suspect the cheaper off-peak saver return ticket on Birmingham Airport to Banbury would not allow you to go so far as Birmingham Stations, but I haven't checked in the routeing guide. If it did allow this, it would be a cheaper alternative.

Comment: By the fact that there is no separate Off-Peak Non-Saver Return listed on [brfares](http://www.brfares.com/#!fares?orig=0418&dest=BAN), I assume that what National Rail lists as “Off-Peak Return” (Crosscountry) is an SVR, is that right?

Comment: If I used it correctly, a [Routeing point calculator](http://data.atoc.org/rp_calc) tells me 'Travel was NOT allowed at NFM64: SDS from BAN to BHM on route 00000: £8.20 is more expensive than SDS from BAN to BHI on route 00211: £7.30.', so no?

Answer (score 1):

National Rail Conditions of Carriage ([PDF](http://www.nationalrail.co.uk/static/documents/content/NRCOC.pdf))

> C. USE OF TICKETS
>
> *16. Starting, breaking or ending a journey at intermediate stations You may start, or break and resume, a journey (in either direction in
>   the case of a return ticket) at any intermediate station, as long as
>   the ticket you hold is valid for the trains you want to use. You may
>   also end your journey (in either direction in the case of a return
>   ticket) before the destination shown on the ticket*

---

Comment: This only applies if the ticket conditions don't say otherwise. Some OFFPEAK R tickets do not allow it on the outbound journey.

Comment: @ Calchas  Yes, you have to go from BHI to BHM first, then go to BAN.